# Trouble adding FULL OUTER JOIN to existing complex query

Tags: sql, outer-join, intersystems-cache

I have a table full of user sessions and I wanted to get the average session times by session type (`MessageBodyClassName`).  I'm getting close, but I have one small issue: The message types with no records show `1` for `MessageCount`.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT mh.MessageBodyClassName as MessageType, 
       count(*) as MessageCount, 
       CAST(AVG(ResponseTime)AS DECIMAL(5,2)) as AvgResponse 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT(MessageBodyClassName) FROM ens.messageheader
    ) mh FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
            li.SessionId,
            li.MessageBodyClassName,
            datediff(s,min(li.TimeCreated),max(lo.TimeCreated)) as ResponseTime
    FROM
        (Select SessionId, TimeCreated, MessageBodyClassName FROM ens.messageheader) li 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (Select SessionId, TimeCreated, MessageBodyClassName FROM ens.messageheader) lo 
      ON li.SessionId = lo.SessionId
    WHERE li.TimeCreated > DATEADD(hh, -1, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY li.SessionId
    ) l ON mh.MessageBodyClassName = l.MessageBodyClassName
GROUP BY mh.MessageBodyClassName
```

Here is a sample of the results:

> ```
> MessageType                            MessageCount AvgResponse 
> -------------------------------------- ------------ ----------- 
> HS.MESSAGE.ADDPATIENTREQUEST           1            (null)      
> HS.MESSAGE.ADDUPDATEHUBREQUEST         525          0.44        
> HS.MESSAGE.GATEWAYREGISTRATIONREQUEST  1            (null)      
> HS.MESSAGE.IDUPDATENOTIFICATIONREQUEST 10           0.51
> ```

Both of the `1`'s above should be `0`.

I tried changing `count(*)` to `count(l.*)` but that doesn't work.  How can I get it to return zero without hacking it (ie `count(*) -1 as MessageCount`)?

Comment: what rdbms? You need include a `JOIN` with all the hours

Comment: a) [tag:intersystems-cache], as tagged.  b) huh? I'm not grouping by hour.  I don't understand.

Comment: Ok, then you need a `JOIN` with all sesion types ;)

Comment: It is listing all the session types (`MessageBodyClassName`) it just has a count of 1 even though there aren't any matching results in the "right table" (I think I'm saying that correctly).

Comment: In you question you say `it will not show up in the list.` so what is it? Show us sample data and expected result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Please read the second half of the question. I was trying to give some context by providing where I started and what my initial objective was.  I will try to simplify it though...

Comment: Sorry for dont read complete, I stop where you say  `my problem is` change `FULL OUTER JOIN` for `LEFT JOIN`, still you need to read how make a better question. You didnt include sample data or expected output. Also you could make an small example in http://rextester.com/ maybe isnt the same db but the logic is the same

Comment: Replacing `FULL OUTER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` gives the same results.

Comment: Then provide sample data so I can work with something ;) better if make a working sample in rextester

Comment: Chage to `LEFT JOIN` and  `COUNT(*)` FOR `COUNT(l.MessageBodyClassName)`

Comment: **[How-to-Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)** :)